# How to scale objects with screen size in Unity

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, game-engine, screen-size

For canvas item no problem, buttons or any other UI elements can be scaled with screensize. On the other hand, I can not do this for objects. I need a box in my design and in every screensize it should fit all screen.

I need this design.
[image]

But when I change screensize design does not remain same.

[image]

other image:

[image]

For button or canvas elements there is no problem I can do it by "scale with screen size" but when it comes to objects I can not do like this. How can I do?

Comment: Well, Stack Overflow is a place where we help you correcting your code, but you have to post your code to show the level of effort you already have put into solving your problem. At that point we help you out, That's how it works ;)

Comment: Thanks but my question is not about coding.

Comment: Well, the solution is through coding, there is no other way to dynamically resize objects based on screen changes, and the code is different depending on the type of camera (orthographic or perspective) and the objects (3D or Sprites).

Comment: So should I investigate objects? or camera?(Because I found some solutions: just writing camera script - But I am not sure and I could not understand totally)

Comment: It depends on the scene you have. if it's made of sprites and your camera is orthographic then you can focus on camera only, but it only works for different screen sizes on the same aspect ratio, such as 720p and 1080p. If you want dynamically adapt to multiple sizes and aspect ratios then there is no simple script that will solve this, you will need a mix of multiple scripts and level design techniques.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a vignette would be useful rather than scaling a gameobject.
**Quick explanation:**

With Unity's post-processing properly added and a volume created, add the effect/override of vignette and change vignette's mode to mask. And add an image as a mask.

**If not experienced with post-processing:**

**For unity 3d HDRP or URP(may work with unity 2d but probably not):**

Add a global volume through the hierarchy by first navigating to the plus sign drop-down then to volume then click on global volume. If unavailable, add an empty object with a volume component. Create a profile then add the override of the vignette. Under vignette change the mode to mask and select an image you want the mask to be.

That should be all for unity HDRP or URP.

**Without HDRP or URP:**

Add the postprocessing package if not installed via the package manager.

Create an empty object and add post-processing volume. Checkmark is-global. Create a new post-processing profile. Add effect vignette. Checkmark 'Mode' and switch it to masked.
Checkmark and change 'Mask' to the image you want.
This should allow the image to pop up over the camera.

*Extra note: Make Sure The Image Has A Transparent Background On The Vignette Mask Where You Want The Player To See Through*

**Please search for how to use post-processing package if any issues occur.**

Comment: I suspect this doesn't solve the OP's issue since it is only a visual solution. If those walls need collisions and such, I don't think the vignette will work